# Storing the output of the print function in a list in recursive function

Tags: xml, recursion, elementtree

```
def get_leaves(node, list_of_leaves=None):
    list_of_leaves = {} if list_of_leaves is None else list_of_leaves
    kids=node.getchildren()
    for i in kids:
        if (i.getchildren()):
            get_leaves(i, list_of_leaves)
        else:
            list_of_leaves[i.tag]=i.text
    print list_of_leaves
    #data.append(list_of_leaves)    
result = {} 
#data=[]
tree = ET.parse('abc.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
get_leaves(root, list_of_leaves=result)
```

---

Whatever I am printing, that is the dictionary in which there are keys as the tags and values are the texts associated with the tag.

I want to store those dictionaries in a list. So, the corresponding list will be a list of a number of dictionaries.

The commented lines show a list '`data`' in which I want to store every dictionary.

I am printing but if I write it the way I have written now, it stores only the last dictionary created.

---